# Use High-charts, Open Flash Chart 2, Google Charts or what else !

Tags: php, google-visualization, open-flash-chart, highcharts

One web application of ours requires a feature of displaying charts in it. Basically we have to show different types of charts for different purposes such as pie charts to give information about some purpose,Bar charts for some other purpose whereas Complex charts for complex data.Note that this charts will be created dynamically depending on the data in the MySQL database so we cannot use simple images.

I have been told to read the integrate this feature in our application.I Google and found **High-charts,Open Flash Chart 2,Google Charts**. What should I use as I don't have experience of integrating charts.

Comment: I got One More for PHP Developers http://pchart.sourceforge.net/ (pCharts) which creates Image of the generated chart

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend taking a look at ZingChart. (I'm on the ZingChart team and your question popped up on my Google Alert).

We allow rendering of charts in both HTML5 and Flash. Many of our customers have migrated from all different libraries and tell us they really enjoy using our framework.

Check us out at http://www.zingchart.com

Feel free to send any questions/feedback to us at support[at]zingchart.com.

Best,
Andrew

Answer (score 1):

The easiest ti implement is:

- Only PHP based: / rendered by GD as image: [pChart](http://pchart.sourceforge.net)
- Flash Based: [FusionCharts](http://www.fusioncharts.com/): Both commercial and free versions are there with almost every kind of chart.